# OptionMenu loses command when updated

Tags: python, tkinter, command, optionmenu

When updating my tkinter OptionMenu called ClientMenu like this:

```
    for i in range(0, len(Clientlist)-1):
    client1d.append(Clientlist[i][0])
ClientMenu.children["menu"].delete(0,len(Clientlist))

for i in range(0, len(Clientlist)):
    nm = Clientlist[i][0]
    client1d.append(nm)
    ClientMenu.children["menu"].add_command(label = nm)

ClientMenu.children["menu"].add_command(label="Add new Client+")
```

This deletes all the entries on the list and then goes through a 1d array containing all the options which go in the menu. This works fine and adds all the  options properly onto the menu.

However the initial command which was in the ClientMenu when it was first defined

`ClientMenu = OptionMenu(screen, dropdown, *client1d,"Add new Client+", command = dropdowncheck)`

the command `dropdowncheck` doesnt run when the menu is recreated however it does before everything is deleted and re added. Is there a way to add back the options as well as add back the "dropdowncheck" command to the OptionMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you give to the OptionMenu is automatically passed to all `add_command` methods in the menu created at that moment. In the `__init__` of the OptionMenu, you can see this like

```
menu.add_command(label=v,
                 command=_setit(variable, v, callback))
```

Because your `add_command` functions pass no command, clicking these options triggers nothing.
In the code above, `_setit` is described as

```
class _setit:
    """Internal class. It wraps the command in the widget OptionMenu."""
```

Basically, this class does two things when called:

1. Set the variable to the new value
2. Call the command with the new value as argument

You could recreate this behavior in a function you write yourself, but the easiest would be to just reuse this class something like:

```
ClientMenu.children["menu"].add_command(label = nm
                                        command =_setit(dropdown, nm, dropdowncheck))
```

Comment: It says that `'_setit' is not defined` when i reference it anywhere in the code (also the code i first posted was all inside a function in case that makes a difference)

Comment: It's just a tkinter class same as OptionMenu. How did you import tkinter? From `ClientMenu = OptionMenu(...)` I guessed you did `from tkinter import *`.

Comment: yeah `from tkinter import *` was what i used

Comment: Oh I get it, underscored classes are not imported with a wildcard import, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). Add `from tkinter import _setit`. (Or stop using a wildcard import altogether and use `import tkinter as tk`. You can then use `tk._setit()`.)

Comment: THANK YOU, you saved my life. I was getting nowhere and without your help i would've never figured it out. (new to python)